# Chosen.js - is it possible to limit the number of items selected?

Tags: javascript, jquery-chosen

I have a client that wants to give users the option to select up to 5 additional options from a list.  I like the Chosen.js concept, but how can I limit the selection?  I suppose one solution is to use the onChange to count the number selected and then disable the remainder, but is there a neater solution?

Comment: you don't need to disable other options, you can uncheck the option which comes 6th to selection and show a message...

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Chosen provides a `max_selected_options` to allow you to do this:

```
$(".chzn-select").chosen({ max_selected_options: 5 });
```

Comment: D'oh!  How did I miss that?  So simple.

Comment: Now the client has changed his mind and wants it done with checkboxes instead.  Thanks to @mccannf for this solution, will be remembered for another day.

Comment: @mccannf can we change the max_selected_options after the initial setup? it does not seem to work if you try to change max_selected_options

Answer (score 0):

max_selected_options: 5 is not working in my case. So I fixed as follows.

```
var countSelect = 0;
$(".chosen-select").chosen().change( function (e, params) {         
    if(params.deselected != undefined) { countSelect--; } 
    if(params.selected != undefined) { countSelect++; } 
    if(countSelect > 3) {           
        $('.chosen-select option[value="'+params.selected+'"]').attr('selected', false);
        $(this).trigger('chosen:updated');
        countSelect--;
    } 
});
```

Try it. Its working very smooth.